# Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 7. Is it legal to install on that device?

Tags: nexus-7

I want to install Ubuntu Touch on multiple devices on Nexus 7. Is it legal.
The reason I am asking is that I am reading that rooting Android tablet devices is technically illegal.

But installing another OS is like  a multi boot install. Is it legal to install another OS on the Nexus? Would appreciate a link to a license doc about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rooting a Android device and installing a Custom ROM or another OS device isn't illegal. You will lost your warranty, that's all.

Comment: When you say warranty, You mean if the Ubuntu software 'bricks' the device. But I should be able to flash back the original Android. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. I have learned that there is always a way to liven up the device again.

Answer (score 0):

They might not like it, but it's not illegal.

If it's a Nexus 7 2012 then I think it's a good idea as the Lollipop update has made it pretty much unusable anyway.

That said, it looks like the 2012 version is no longer supported by Ubuntu touch.